# customize CRUD operation in loopback js

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

i am new to loopback js trying to create remote method Create,Read,update and delete operation.
i have created a model name class and now i want to write the crud operation in my project file 
models/class.js file.

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(Class) {

};
```

I have no idea how to do it , read docs but does not clearify things if anyone can give example to write CRUD operation would be better understanding. (Using loopback 3 for practice.)

Comment: [This](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Extend-your-API.html) guide has some explanation

Comment: @Salitha I read the document as new to these how can i create my own CRUD remote method . like how can i write sql query for create in my .js file

Answer (score 0):

To create a custom method for a model, you need to do two things:

1/ Create the method within your model like this:

```js
module.exports = function (Mymodel) {
  Mymodel.myCustomMethod = function (req, res, cb) {
    // method body
  }
}
```

2/ To declare the remote to your model, so it can be exposed

```js
module.exports = function (Mymodel) {
  /* custom methods, hooks, ... */

  Mymodel.remoteMethod(
    'myCustomMethod', {
      http: {
        path: '/myCustomMethod',
        verb: 'post' // it could also be 'post', 'put', 'delete'
      },
      accepts: {
        arg: 'data',
        type: 'object', // accepting an object in the body
        'http': {
          source: 'body' // Reading the body of the request. It could also be 'req' to read the req url for parameters.
        }
      },
      returns: {
        type: 'object', // Returns an object to the front
        root: true
      }
    }
  )
}
```

This is an example for a 'post' remote method. A 'put' remote method will look exactly the same, except for the keyword 'put' instead of 'post'.

For a 'get' or 'delete' requests, only the request url will be read, so the remote method should contain:

```js
http: { path: '/myCustomMethod/:projectId', verb: 'get' },
accepts: { arg: 'projectId', type: 'number' },
```

With `projectId` the name of a property given in the URL, and `number` being the type of `projectId`.